# NSURL getResourceValue in swift

Tags: url, swift

Having trouble figuring out how to make the following call in swift:

```
var anyError: NSError? = nil
var rsrc: NSNumber? = nil
var success = url.getResourceValue(&rsrc, forKey:NSURLIsUbiquitousItemKey, error:&anyError)
```

The above does not compile:

```
Cannot convert the expression's type 'Bool' to type 'inout Bool'
```

So I tried this:

```
var anyError: NSError? = nil
var rsrc: AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<AnyObject?> = nil
var success = url.getResourceValue(rsrc, forKey:NSURLIsUbiquitousItemKey, error:&anyError)
```

but this generates `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` runtime error.

How do I pass in the expected first arg as `AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<AnyObject?>` (which  should point to a boolean NSNumber according to doc), and then be able to check its expected Bool value ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to make `rsrc` an optional AnyObject and pass it by reference like so:

```
var anyError: NSError?
var rsrc: AnyObject?
var success = url.getResourceValue(&rsrc, forKey:NSURLIsUbiquitousItemKey, error:&anyError)
```

**Note**: You do not need to initialize Optionals to nil, they are set to nil by default.

If you then want to check if the value is an NSNumber you can then do a conversion:

```
if let number = rsrc as? NSNumber {
    // use number
}
```

Comment: Thanks, had not tried that, although I had become quite creative in my attempts... The answer was indeed right in my question. Thanks. Will accept.

Answer (score 7):

Here is drewag's code updated for Swift 2.0

```
    do {
        var rsrc: AnyObject?
        try element.getResourceValue(&rsrc, forKey: NSURLIsDirectoryKey)
        if let number = rsrc as? NSNumber {
            if number == true {
                // do something
            }
        }
    } catch {
    }
```

Comment: This code gives a segmentation fault 11, any idea why ?

Answer (score 6):

in swift 3 previous calls are not available/deprecated:

so use:

```
var keys = Set<URLResourceKey>()
keys.insert(URLResourceKey.isDirectoryKey)
do{
    let URLResourceValues = try fileURL.resourceValues(forKeys: keys)
    }catch _{

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the getResourceValue(:forKey:) result is ultimately a logical value, you can cast the returned pointer value directly to a Bool value:

```
let boolResult = rsrc as! Bool
```

or simply test it as a Bool value without assigning it:

```
if rsrc as! Bool {
    // true code
} else {
    // false code
}
```

or do both:

```
if let rsrc as! Bool {
    // true
} else {
    // false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a concrete example as an extension of the URL type:

```
extension URL {
    var creationDate : Date {
        let url = self as NSURL
        var value : AnyObject?
        try? url.getResourceValue(&value, forKey: .creationDateKey)
        if let date = value as? Date {
            return date
        }
        return .distantPast
    }
}
```

For convenience, if the call to `getResourceValue()` fails, it returns the value `.distantPast` by default. Using the `try?` form allows discarding the error which isn't always needed.